# it is possible that asp.net app communicate with php app through ajax call?

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, ajax, http

I have a **scenario that API part is written in PHP and website design in asp.net.`** 
My question is if both apps deploy on the same server then asp.net can call API request with ajax call?

`e-g: '../api?action=test'`.

I think it is possible in HTTP request.

Comment: it's possible but what would you like to achieve ?

Comment: @Ted json response from api

Comment: I'm guessing the that the `ajax` bit, means that an asp.net page will call a `php` page via `JavaScript`, right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible and it will work as long as your server can process each language (ASP & PHP should be installed on it).

The ASP.NET will call the API via Ajax and only cares about the response it gets (so it doesn't matter if the code is generated via PHP, Node.JS or is static HTML).

Comment: what do you mean "it will work as long as your server can process both languages"?

Comment: @Ted : I might rewrite this sentence, since its unclear. I mean that obviously the server has to have PHP and ASP installed in order to process each of the languages. Most of the hosting providers only provide PHP or ASP and not both.

Comment: @brclz if my api folder name rest and my asp.net project name is web both are in same folder. web folder have view file test from there i have to create ajax call what will be url?

Comment: @RazaSaleem It depends on your server configuration. If you have a single webserver running and that it points to the root folder that contains the two folders, you would have `/rest` and `/web`. So from the ASP you can call the api at `/rest` with AJAX.